# "Load key "/Users/uname/.ssh/id_rsa": Is a directory

Tags: ssh

I tied to save my keygen with:

```
sudo ssh-copy-id -f -i id_rsa/uname.pub name@host
```

But I get this error when I try to ssh:

```
"Load key "/Users/uname/.ssh/id_rsa"
```

Why?

My `.pub` file is in `/Users/uname/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 3):

The (open)ssh client will attempt to read [certain filenames](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#FILES) on the assumption that they contain your private key:

```
~/.ssh/identity
~/.ssh/id_dsa
~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
~/.ssh/id_ed25519
~/.ssh/id_rsa
    Contains the private key for authentication.
```

Since you appear to have an `id_rsa` *directory*, you would need to use the [`-i` option to tell `ssh` where your private key is](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#DESCRIPTION):

```
-i identity_file

   Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authentication is read.
```

Alternatively, move your private keys into your `~/.ssh/` directory directly, being careful to temporarily rename any `id_rsa` key file so that you can remove the emptied `id_rsa` directory. If you then name your key(s) with a filename that `ssh` expects, you can avoid having to specify `-i` all the time.